# Is it possible to get formatted address from latitude and longitude using google places textsearch api?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I want to display a formatted address on click of map pin.

Google's textseach api giving key formatted_address. How can I use to get formatted_address for particular latitude-longitude for that particular place?

Is it possible to get formatted address from latitude and longitude using google places textsearch api?

Comment: You would want to use the Google Maps API and the Reverse Geocode functionality.

Comment: I want to use Google web services api.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) to get the address.

Example: https:// maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.1309601,72.9068758&key=*your-key*

PS: Multiple results will be returned most of the time.

Comment: Actually I need only one result for that particular latitude and longitude.

Comment: There is no such provision in the API to limit the results. You can anyway pick the first result.